# How can I compare two System.Types?

Tags: c#

I have done this a gazillion times before but my memory fails me and I feel somewhat stupid asking this.

How do I compare two runtime types? I assume System.Type does not override the == operator and therefore the operator does a reference equality check.

I want to do a value equality. Like:

```
someObject.GetType() == GetTypeFromSomeAssemblyUsingReflection(
                                                "Namespace.TypeName",
                                                objAssemblyToGetTheTypeFrom);
```

I could use `IsAssignableFrom()` but that would not be accurately what I am trying to do as it would broaden the scope. I want to just equate the types just as I'd do with:

```
if obj is Cat // where Cat is the name of a class
```

or

```
if ( (obj as Cat) != null )
```

Comment: Why assume when you can quickly test it out?

Comment: Don't forget to mark your favorite answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `==` operator should do the trick for type equality checks. For example, this passes:

```
[Test]
public void TypeEquality()
{
    var monkey = new Monkey();
    var areEqual = (monkey.GetType() == typeof(Monkey));
    Assert.That(areEqual, Is.True);
}
```

Comment: It appears you are correct. I did not know this, but the MSDN documentation seems to agree: "A Type object that represents a type is unique; that is, two Type object references refer to the same object if and only if they represent the same type. This allows for comparison of Type objects using reference equality." http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.aspx

Answer (score 4):

Type [does override the equality operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.op_equality.aspx), as seen in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

If you want `obj is Cat` behavior, `IsAssignableFrom` does actually work:

```
obj is Cat
```

is equivalent to:

```
typeof(Cat).IsAssignableFrom(obj.GetType())
```

For instance:

```
object siamese = new SiameseCat();

bool a = siamese is Cat;

// this is functionaly equivalent.
bool b = typeof(Cat).IsAssignableFrom(siamese.GetType());
```

Comment: Your IsAssignableFrom calls are wrong (b is false). You want: typeof (Cat).IsAssignableFrom (obj.GetType ())

Comment: @Jb: You are absolutely right. Fixed it. I always seem to turn that call around.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( obj1.GetType().FullName == obj2.GetType().FullName )
```

if you need to create the object from an assembly dynamically, use such a method:

```
public object createObjectFromAsm( string asm, string type )
{
    // get the domain
    AppDomain ad = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
    // create the object handle from the assembly
    System.Runtime.Remoting.ObjectHandle sVal = ad.CreateInstanceFrom( asm, type );
    // unwrap the object
    return sVal.Unwrap();
}
```